# can we install another application from our android apllication?

Tags: android

i am using a augmented reality in my android application. 
For this i am using the wikitude api. This api requires the phone to have the wikitude browser installed in our phone. if it is not there is a provision that i can show a message that the apk file is not available on your phone.

When the above message is shown that the wikitude broswer is unavailable on the phone, i want to install the brower on the user's phone using the code in my application.

Right now i am providing a link to the android market where the wikitude browser lies, rather than redirecting him to this url, i want to install the app directly in the phone without the user ever knowing that there is another app being installed in the background from the android market.

is this possible in android?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a bad idea to try to install any kind of software without letting your users know about it. And there are permissions that user must accept, you cannot just overcome this. So the only solution for you is to redirect the user to the market and let him know that he won't be able to use your application without having the other one installed.

Comment: i do not wish to let the user redirect to any other activity. i want him to stay in my activity and have the installation in the background....this setup would be more user friendly. i can take all the permisssions that the app requires from my app and then pass them along to the installation code. that way the user permissions are also taken care of.